# mysql_query returning boolean or string?

Tags: mysql, string, boolean

For some reason when I run a `$result=mysql_query(...)` that should return an array to be parsed with `mysql_fetch_array`, I keep getting an error that the value returned for `$result` is either a string or boolean, which `mysql_fetch_array()` can't work with. I've been running the same query on my server for years and for some reason it stopped working recently.

here's the sample code:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `patient_list`");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
...
}
```

I recently upgraded to the newest version of wamp. might that have anything to do with it? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This error means taht result of mysql_query is not valid.Please place

```
echo mysql_error();
```

after you call mysql_query

Answer (score 0):

Your problem could be access / database doesn't exist / anything

Always check the query runs correctly execute your query like this :

```
$result = mysql_query(<query>);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}

// process the result here
```

[Documentation for mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `patient_list`") or die( mysql_error() );
```

Comment: By the way, it can be helpful to write queries this way all the time, because if you get a mysql_query error, your program won't work anyway — but this way you'll get a message immediately )